# Does the string_split function create a new table for each record in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that takes a string of courses (Up to about 8,000 records) that I pass in and check against my results. I am using the `string_split` function in SQL Server that returns a table.

I am using it in my where clause to filter out courses that are not in the list.

What I am curious about is whether it creates the table for each record or only once.

If it creates a new table for each record then tests it, I would think I would want to create a temporary table, fill it using the `string_split` function and then use a join on that table. Not sure if it matters.

The code looks like:

```
SELECT @propList = '438678,438679,'

SELECT top 10  * 
from CourseProposals cpr
WHERE cpr.id in (SELECT trim(VALUE) FROM string_split(@propList, ','))
```

[image: execution plan]

Thanks

Comment: Of course you could just try it both ways and compare the execution plan :)

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question. You could also `inner join` with the results from `String_Split` rather than using it in the `where` clause.

Comment: If the string_split is part of a Join, would it only execute once? Also, in the execution plan it shows inside a nested loop. Does that mean it executes each loop (creates table).

Answer (score 1):

It's plan-dependent behavior.  Often `string_split` will run once, but it's not guaranteed.  For instance this:

```
use tempdb 
go
drop table if exists CourseProposals

go

create table CourseProposals(id int)
insert into CourseProposals(id) values (438678)
insert into CourseProposals(id) values (438676)
go
declare @propList varchar(max)
SELECT @propList = '438678,438679,'

SELECT top 10  * 
from CourseProposals cpr
WHERE cpr.id in (SELECT trim(VALUE) FROM string_split(@propList, ','))
```

runs `string_split` for each row in the `CourseProposals` table:

[image]

If you want to be sure `string_split` only runs once insert the values into a temp table or table variable.